# Xdebug not showing PHP variables in Notepad++ (XAMPP environment)

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, notepad++, xdebug

I need to debug my PHP scripts in a local environment but I'm having a "small" problem with my current set-up.

I was able to successfully install Xdebug, XAMPP, and the DBGp plugin for Notepad++.

**The problem is that Xdebug is not showing up PHP variables in Notepad++**

[image]

I already tried to disable OPCache, but it doesn't seem to be enough. `phpinfo()` seems to be fine..

These are my php.ini settings:

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=0
;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0-7.2-vc15.dll

[xdebug]
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.max_depth=1
```

**Any ideas on how to make this work?**

Comment: Try downgrading Xdebug to 2.6.x. *May* help.

Comment: Tried that as well, same problem. The Eval box works when I type $a, however, variables are still not displayed in the context views.